# How to solve borrow checker failure when working with struct functions?

Tags: rust

On reflection, the title of this question should perhaps be something like:

***How to call a struct member function which take mutable references `&mut self` from another struct member function where a reference has been borrowed?***

But that's a very long title, and I suspect makes the question *less* searchable rather than more searchable.

---

This is a frequent issue I run into when working with Rust.

I have a struct consisting of several "parts", which I am using independently. I know there are no reference lifetime problems or ownership problems, but the borrow checker doesn't know that.

This typically occurs when I am working with a struct containing multiple containers/collection types.

Here is an example from some code I was just working with. It is a somewhat contrived example, because I cannot post the original code, but this works for demonstration purposes.

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

struct MyData {
    
    data: i32,
    another_data: i32,
}

struct ContainsTwoThings {
    
    thing1: BTreeMap<i32, VecDeque<MyData>>,
    thing2: VecDeque<MyData>,
}

impl ContainsTwoThings {
    
    fn process_event_queue(&mut self,
        index: &i32
    )
    {
        // Only do something if `index` exists,
        // and the data it references has a particular value
        match self.thing1.get_mut(index) {

            Some(queue) => {

                while let Some(element) = queue.front() {
                    if element.data >= 4 { // some magic number
                        // This represents some condition where we do something
                        let element = queue.pop_front().unwrap(); // we know it exists
                        self.process_it(element, index);
                    }
                    else {
                        // For whatever reason we break here
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            None => {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    
    fn process_it(&mut self, element: MyData, index: &i32) {
        println!("index: {}, element.data = {}", index, element.data);
    }
}


fn main() {
    
    let mut my_struct = ContainsTwoThings {
        thing1: BTreeMap::new(),
        thing2: VecDeque::new(),
    };
}
```

This is the error message:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:34:25
   |
26 |         match self.thing1.get_mut(index) {
   |               -------------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
30 |                 while let Some(element) = queue.front() {
   |                                           ------------- first borrow later used here
...
34 |                         self.process_it(element, index);
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I know **some ways** to solve this problem. Typically I would either:

- use `std::mem::take` to rip ownership of `thing1` away from the `&self`, possibly to put it back later
- create a new temporary variable to hold a copy of the data in `thing1` and operate on that temporary, possibly copying back any remaining data afterwards back into `self.thing1`

This seems like a common issue that must be encountered by others on a fairly regular basis.

I know what I am trying to do is safe and will result in the correct, expected, executable code, when compiled. I am just not allowed to compile it because Rust can't figure out that although I am borrowing a reference which comes from `thing1` which itself comes from `&mut self`, the function `process_it` will not operate on `thing1`. Instead it operates on `thing2`. (Code for this not shown, as it turned out not to actually be relevant. All that matters from the `rustc` point of view is we call a function which takes a `&self` while part of `self` is borrowed.)

Comment: Yeah, Rust unfortunately has no way of analyzing which fields are actually borrowed across function boundaries, or annotating a method with the fields it actually borrows. Your best bet is probably to just create (static) functions that take precisely the fields they need, and nothing else, and call those instead.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the straightforward fix is to make `process_it` into a free function — no `self` parameter.

```rust
fn process_it(element: MyData, index: &i32) {
    println!("index: {}, element.data = {}", index, element.data);
}
```

If you need a field from `ContainsTwoThings` — presumably `Thing2` — then pass a reference to that field. If you have a lot of such fields, it is often the case that you can usefully organize your data by adding *more structs*, like so:

```rust
struct ContainsTwoThings {
    thing1: BTreeMap<i32, VecDeque<MyData>>,
    other_things: OtherThings,
}
struct OtherThings {
    thing2: VecDeque<MyData>,
}
```

Now you can pass `&mut self.other_things` to `process_it` conveniently — perhaps even moving `process_it` into an `impl OtherThings`, if that makes sense.